# MSB3073: The command "mc :VCEnd" exited with code 1

Tags: c++, log4cpp

I am trying to compile log4cpp_x86 in visual studio 2019, but it gives me the error as below,[image]

I tried to change the location of the project from D: to C:, but still problem persist, and also I unmarked the folder as ReadOnly but it also doesn't work.

also when I click on the error i.e marked with MSB3073 it redirects me to the line in Microsoft.CppCommon.targets, which has the xml tag as:

```
  <Exec Command="%(CustomBuildStep.Command)$(_BuildSuffix)"/>
```

Comment: @HansPassant  But there is no post-build command written in Build Events, however I saw that command in C++ project solution file as under,



 `<CustomBuildStep>
      <Command>mc $(InputPath)</Command>
    </CustomBuildStep>`

Comment: Somebody else had this problem, consider using [the workaround](https://christophep.wordpress.com/2018/02/22/building-log4cpp-with-vs2017/) he found.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for that link..I tried that solution ,but after executing **add HAVE_SNPRINTF to the Preprocessor definitions** ,  it gives me 
**Error : C2084 log4cpp_x86  function 'int vsnprintf(char *const ,const size_t,const char *const ,va_list)' already has a body**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [link](https://christophep.wordpress.com/2018/02/22/building-log4cpp-with-vs2017/) is suggested by the @HansPassant its the half solution in my case, but before following procedure suggested in that link, I replaced the whole log4cpp project having corrupted solution file with xml tag as below,

```
<CustomBuildStep> <Command>mc $(InputPath)</Command> </CustomBuildStep>
```

with old project having solution file with below tags,

```
<CustomBuild Include="..\NTEventLogCategories.mc">
      <Command Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug with Boost|Win32'">"$(VS100COMNTOOLS)vsvars32.bat" if not exist $(OutDir) md $(OutDir)
mc.exe -h "$(OutDir)" -r "$(OutDir)" "$(ProjectDir)..\%(Filename).mc"
rc.exe -r -fo "$(OutDir)%(Filename).res" "$(OutDir)%(Filename).rc"
link.exe /MACHINE:IX86 -dll -noentry -out:"$(OutDir)NTEventLogAppender.dll" "$(OutDir)%(Filename).res"
</Command>
      <Command Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug with Boost|x64'">"$(VS100COMNTOOLS)vsvars32.bat" if not exist $(OutDir) md $(OutDir)
mc.exe -h "$(OutDir)" -r "$(OutDir)" "$(ProjectDir)..\%(Filename).mc"
rc.exe -r -fo "$(OutDir)%(Filename).res" "$(OutDir)%(Filename).rc"
link.exe /MACHINE:IX86 -dll -noentry -out:"$(OutDir)NTEventLogAppender.dll" "$(OutDir)%(Filename).res"
</Command>
      <Outputs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug with Boost|Win32'">$(OutDir)NTEventLogAppender.dll;%(Outputs)</Outputs>
      <Outputs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug with Boost|x64'">$(OutDir)NTEventLogAppender.dll;%(Outputs)</Outputs>
      <Command Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">"$(VS100COMNTOOLS)vsvars32.bat" if not exist $(OutDir) md $(OutDir)
mc.exe -h "$(OutDir)" -r "$(OutDir)" "$(ProjectDir)..\%(Filename).mc"
rc.exe -r -fo "$(OutDir)%(Filename).res" "$(OutDir)%(Filename).rc"
link.exe /MACHINE:IX86 -dll -noentry -out:"$(OutDir)NTEventLogAppender.dll" "$(OutDir)%(Filename).res"
</Command>
      <Command Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">"$(VS100COMNTOOLS)vsvars32.bat" if not exist $(OutDir) md $(OutDir)
mc.exe -h "$(OutDir)" -r "$(OutDir)" "$(ProjectDir)..\%(Filename).mc"
rc.exe -r -fo "$(OutDir)%(Filename).res" "$(OutDir)%(Filename).rc"
link.exe /MACHINE:IX86 -dll -noentry -out:"$(OutDir)NTEventLogAppender.dll" "$(OutDir)%(Filename).res"
</Command>
      <Outputs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">$(OutDir)NTEventLogAppender.dll;%(Outputs)</Outputs>
      <Outputs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">$(OutDir)NTEventLogAppender.dll;%(Outputs)</Outputs>
      <Command Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release with Boost|Win32'">"$(VS100COMNTOOLS)vsvars32.bat" if not exist $(OutDir) md $(OutDir)
mc.exe -h $(OutDir) -r $(OutDir) $(ProjectDir)..\%(Filename).mc
RC.exe -r -fo $(OutDir)%(Filename).res $(OutDir)%(Filename).rc
link.exe /MACHINE:IX86 -dll -noentry -out:$(OutDir)NTEventLogAppender.dll $(OutDir)%(Filename).res
</Command>
      <Command Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release with Boost|x64'">"$(VS100COMNTOOLS)vsvars32.bat" if not exist $(OutDir) md $(OutDir)
mc.exe -h $(OutDir) -r $(OutDir) $(ProjectDir)..\%(Filename).mc
RC.exe -r -fo $(OutDir)%(Filename).res $(OutDir)%(Filename).rc
link.exe /MACHINE:IX86 -dll -noentry -out:$(OutDir)NTEventLogAppender.dll $(OutDir)%(Filename).res
</Command>
      <Outputs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release with Boost|Win32'">$(OutDir)NTEventLogAppender.dll;%(Outputs)</Outputs>
      <Outputs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release with Boost|x64'">$(OutDir)NTEventLogAppender.dll;%(Outputs)</Outputs>
      <Command Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">"$(VS100COMNTOOLS)vsvars32.bat" if not exist $(OutDir) md $(OutDir)
mc.exe -h $(OutDir) -r $(OutDir) $(ProjectDir)..\%(Filename).mc
RC.exe -r -fo $(OutDir)%(Filename).res $(OutDir)%(Filename).rc
link.exe /MACHINE:IX86 -dll -noentry -out:$(OutDir)NTEventLogAppender.dll $(OutDir)%(Filename).res
</Command>
      <Command Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">"$(VS100COMNTOOLS)vsvars32.bat" if not exist $(OutDir) md $(OutDir)
mc.exe -h $(OutDir) -r $(OutDir) $(ProjectDir)..\%(Filename).mc
RC.exe -r -fo $(OutDir)%(Filename).res $(OutDir)%(Filename).rc
link.exe /MACHINE:IX86 -dll -noentry -out:$(OutDir)NTEventLogAppender.dll $(OutDir)%(Filename).res
</Command>
      <Outputs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">$(OutDir)NTEventLogAppender.dll;%(Outputs)</Outputs>
      <Outputs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">$(OutDir)NTEventLogAppender.dll;%(Outputs)</Outputs>
    </CustomBuild>
```

And then I followed the steps of the link as suggested by @HansPassant, however I didn't followed first step(i.e. download new version of log4cpp) in that [link](https://christophep.wordpress.com/2018/02/22/building-log4cpp-with-vs2017/), rather I replaced the project with old project and then followed all the procedure according to suggestions in that link, and that solved my problem.